# queryDSL - elasticsearch - must along with must-not doesnot give expected result

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

**Elasticsearch 7.8.1**

**Requirement**
Fetch documents with `req_uri property equal to /api/data` and without `- in  enduser_email`

but the results i receive has `-` in `enduser_email`

**Query DSL**

```
get infolog-2020-08-25/_search
{
  "_source" : ["req_uri","referrer","enduser_email","request_timestamp"],
  "query" : {
    "bool":{
      "must" : [
        {
          "match":{
            "req_uri" : "/api/data"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match":{
            "enduser_email":  "-"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My requirement is simple but i'm struggling with this query in elasticsearch

**Index mapping**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you share your index mapping as well, please?

Comment: @Val i have added a portion of indexMapping to the question. why is index mapping data required for this question, my indexMapping contains large data, you need the whole thing?what data has to be verified there?

Comment: I know you got an answer to your question but it would be great if you could share an example of a document. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `keyword` subfield instead:

```
get infolog-2020-08-25/_search
{
  "_source" : ["req_uri","referrer","enduser_email","request_timestamp"],
  "query" : {
    "bool":{
      "must" : [
        {
          "match":{
            "req_uri.keyword" : "/api/data"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match":{
            "enduser_email.keyword":  "-"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```